# Adal Login issues with authentication

Tags: android, mobile, office365, adal

I'm trying microsoft adal login authentication in my android application. But when ever I login with Office 365 I'm getting the following error here I'm sharing the error log & library which I'm using "com.microsoft.aad:adal:1.13.1"

Can anyone find out why it is failing with my office 365 account & I'm able to successfully login with other office 365 accounts. Is it issue my account?

Thanks in advance.

```
04-06 10:48:41.785 9224-9353/test.ms.authentication E/HttpWebRequest: SERVER_ERROR:2018-04-06 05:18:41-fe96c34f-dd35-4d07-98ee-cdff28eab452-IOException:unexpected end of stream on Connection{login.windows.net:443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=40.112.64.25 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0) ver:1.13.1 
04-06 10:48:41.791 9224-9353/test.ms.authentication E/Oauth: SERVER_ERROR:2018-04-06 05:18:41-fe96c34f-dd35-4d07-98ee-cdff28eab452-unexpected end of stream on Connection{login.windows.net:443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=40.112.64.25 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0) ver:1.13.1 
                                                              java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{login.windows.net:443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=40.112.64.25 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:210)
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:906)
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:782)
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:463)
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243)
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
                                                                  at com.microsoft.aad.adal.HttpWebRequest.send(HttpWebRequest.java:130)
                                                                  at com.microsoft.aad.adal.WebRequestHandler.sendPost(WebRequestHandler.java:76)
                                                                  at com.microsoft.aad.adal.Oauth2.postMessage(Oauth2.java:455)
                                                                  at com.microsoft.aad.adal.Oauth2.getTokenForCode(Oauth2.java:435)
                                                                  at com.microsoft.aad.adal.Oauth2.getToken(Oauth2.java:396)
                                                                  at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenInteractiveRequest.acquireTokenWithAuthCode(AcquireTokenInteractiveRequest.java:95)
                                                                  at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest$3.run(AcquireTokenRequest.java:675)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                               Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=...
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:200)
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80) 
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:906) 
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:782) 
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:463) 
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405) 
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243) 
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210) 
                                                                  at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) 
                                                                  at com.microsoft.aad.adal.HttpWebRequest.send(HttpWebRequest.java:130) 
                                                                  at com.microsoft.aad.adal.WebRequestHandler.sendPost(WebRequestHandler.java:76) 
                                                                  at com.microsoft.aad.adal.Oauth2.postMessage(Oauth2.java:455) 
                                                                  at com.microsoft.aad.adal.Oauth2.getTokenForCode(Oauth2.java:435) 
                                                                  at com.microsoft.aad.adal.Oauth2.getToken(Oauth2.java:396) 
                                                                  at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenInteractiveRequest.acquireTokenWithAuthCode(AcquireTokenInteractiveRequest.java:95) 
                                                                  at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest$3.run(AcquireTokenRequest.java:675) 
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
04-06 10:48:41.798 9224-9353/test.ms.authentication E/AcquireTokenRequest: AUTHORIZATION_CODE_NOT_EXCHANGED_FOR_TOKEN:2018-04-06 05:18:41-fe96c34f-dd35-4d07-98ee-cdff28eab452-Error in processing code to get token. Request authority:https://login.windows.net/abccompanynet.onmicrosoft.com resource:https://graph.windows.net clientid:7feaade0-79a7-4c96-b643-c78c41cf4ec3 CorrelationId: fe96c34f-dd35-4d07-98ee-cdff28eab452unexpected end of stream on Connection{login.windows.net:443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=40.112.64.25 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0) ver:1.13.1 Error in processing code to get token. Request authority:https://login.windows.net/abccompanynet.onmicrosoft.com resource:https://graph.windows.net clientid:7feaade0-79a7-4c96-b643-c78c41cf4ec3 CorrelationId: fe96c34f-dd35-4d07-98ee-cdff28eab452
                                                                            com.microsoft.aad.adal.AuthenticationException: Error in processing code to get token. Request authority:https://login.windows.net/abccompanynet.onmicrosoft.com resource:https://graph.windows.net clientid:7feaade0-79a7-4c96-b643-c78c41cf4ec3 CorrelationId: fe96c34f-dd35-4d07-98ee-cdff28eab452
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenInteractiveRequest.acquireTokenWithAuthCode(AcquireTokenInteractiveRequest.java:101)
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest$3.run(AcquireTokenRequest.java:675)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
                                                                             Caused by: java.io.IOException: unexpected end of stream on Connection{login.windows.net:443, proxy=DIRECT hostAddress=40.112.64.25 cipherSuite=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:210)
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80)
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:906)
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:782)
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:463)
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405)
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243)
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java)
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.HttpWebRequest.send(HttpWebRequest.java:130)
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.WebRequestHandler.sendPost(WebRequestHandler.java:76)
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.Oauth2.postMessage(Oauth2.java:455)
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.Oauth2.getTokenForCode(Oauth2.java:435)
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.Oauth2.getToken(Oauth2.java:396)
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenInteractiveRequest.acquireTokenWithAuthCode(AcquireTokenInteractiveRequest.java:95)
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest$3.run(AcquireTokenRequest.java:675) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
                                                                             Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=...
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:200)
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.readResponse(HttpConnection.java:191)
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport.readResponseHeaders(HttpTransport.java:80) 
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readNetworkResponse(HttpEngine.java:906) 
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:782) 
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:463) 
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:405) 
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:243) 
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210) 
                                                                                at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) 
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.HttpWebRequest.send(HttpWebRequest.java:130) 
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.WebRequestHandler.sendPost(WebRequestHandler.java:76) 
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.Oauth2.postMessage(Oauth2.java:455) 
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.Oauth2.getTokenForCode(Oauth2.java:435) 
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.Oauth2.getToken(Oauth2.java:396) 
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenInteractiveRequest.acquireTokenWithAuthCode(AcquireTokenInteractiveRequest.java:95) 
                                                                                at com.microsoft.aad.adal.AcquireTokenRequest$3.run(AcquireTokenRequest.java:675) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
04-06 10:48:41.799 9224-9353/test.ms.authentication V/AcquireTokenRequest: 2018-04-06 05:18:41-fe96c34f-dd35-4d07-98ee-cdff28eab452-Sending error to callback CorrelationId: fe96c34f-dd35-4d07-98ee-cdff28eab452 ver:1.13.1
04-06 10:48:41.801 9224-9353/test.ms.authentication V/AuthenticationContext: 2018-04-06 05:18:41-fe96c34f-dd35-4d07-98ee-cdff28eab452-Remove waiting request: 105490614 ver:1.13.1
04-06 10:48:45.701 9224-9494/test.ms.authentication V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: \n not found: size=0 content=...
```

Check your log this is your problem

check out this issue https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android/issues/418

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue & got it fixed by clearing the cache

```
 react-native start --reset-cache
```

Repro steps:

1. Login successfully(don't signout)
2. Close the app and reopen OR login back without proper logout.

As the last token(when successfully logged in token) is stored in cache, it gets ambiguity and gives the mentioned error.

Handle the cache, silent-signin, singout properly should avoid this problem going forward.